# In Pycharm, global variables are not autocompleted inside functions when declared global for assignment

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

while using pycharm 3.1 with python3 if i type something simple like

```
v = ['z', 'e', 't', 'z']
def foo():
    v.sort()
    print(v)
```

it auto-completes v just fine recognizes v as a list and sort() is shown in the autocomplete results

however if the variable was to be set inside the function pycharm doesn't recognize it as a list and doesn't auto complete

```
v = ['z', 'e', 't']
def foo():
    global v
    v.append('o')
    v.sort()
    print(v)
```

at any point inside the function after global v , pycharm does not autocomplete the variable v

is there a logical reason for this in python itself i am not aware of? or could this be a pycharm bug?

Comment: It works for me with pycharm 3.1 and python 2.7.5

Comment: Why are you asking this on SO? So is not a PyCharm bug tracking site. Open a ticket [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) instead.

Comment: as stated in my question I'm asking if there is a reason in python itself that i may not be aware of and this is the correct behavior like maybe for example declaring a variable global affect it's type somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example using [ipython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython) and the autocomplete works fine so it must be a pycharm issue.

Note that the use of global variables is discouraged in python unless you have a very good reason for it.